# why do I get error in Django : unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'Model' and 'Model'

Tags: django

So I have a model named `Question`. There are three types of objects in `Question`, and I'm trying to query those objects separately, then merge first objects of each. Like this:

```
def getQuestion(request):    
    typeOne = Question.objects.filter(type=1).order_by('question_number')
    typeTwo = Question.objects.filter(type=2).order_by('question_number')
    typeThree = Question.objects.filter(type=3).order_by('question_number')
   
    questionsOfTheDay = typeOne[0] | typeTwo[0] | typeThree[0]
    
    # I've tried below as well, with chain imported
    # questionsOfTheDay = chain(typeOne[0], typeTwo[0], typeThree[0])

    serialized = QuestionSerializer(questionsOfTheDay, many=True)

    return Response(serialized.data)
```

I don't see what I've done wrong, but I keep getting the error "unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'Question' and 'Question'".
What do you think is the problem? I appreciate it in advance.

Comment: could you explain what this line is intending to do? 'questionsOfTheDay = depthOne[0] | depthTwo[0] | depthThree[0]'.  What do you believe the pipe is intended to do here? Python uses 'or', not pipe, as the logical 'or' operator.... I honestly am not sure what this line is supposd to be assigning to questionsOfTheDay, can you clarify?

Comment: @m.arthur Oh I'm so sorry. I forgot to make changes. the ```depth``` is actually ```type```. I made changes in the code. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def getQuestion(request):
    questionOfTheDay = Question.objects.filter( Q(type=1) | Q(type=2) | Q(type=3)).order_by('question_number')
    #Or .filter(type__in[1,2,3]).order_by('question_number')    
    serialized = QuestionSerializer(questionsOfTheDay, many=True)
    return Response(serialized.data)
```

And problem in your code is `typeOne`,`typeTwo` and `typeThree` are querysets. You can perform `|` on querysets.

but when you write `typeOne[0]` it access it's first object and `|` can't be done with objects.

so it should be

```
questionsOfTheDay = typeOne | typeTwo | typeThree
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I understood from OP: You need to have a `QuerySet` of **`Question`** with *"type=1 or type=2 or type=3"*

If so, you can simply use the [**`in`**--(Django Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup

```
def getQuestion(request):
    questionsOfTheDay = Question.objects.filter(
        type__in=[1, 2, 3]).order_by('question_number')

    serialized = QuestionSerializer(questionsOfTheDay, many=True)
    return Response(serialized.data)
```